# What rhumb lines of a torus are periodic $C^1$ curves?

Tags: differential-geometry

This is a question coming from an old (French) geometry book.

Take a 3D torus. Study the rhumb lines of the torus and find the ones that are periodic $C^1$ curves. **In particular, it is mentioned that the meridian circles are not the only periodic rhumb lines.**

I tried to write the equations of the rhumb lines, but I'm not able to find the periodic ones apart from the meridian circles. **Do you have a clue on what could be those additional rhumb Lines?**

For the record:

- The rhumb lines are the one crossing the meridian circles with a constant angle.
- The meridian circles are the one lying in planes containing the axis of revolution of the torus.

Comment: Arent the periodic lines precisely the images (under the identification of sides of the square) of lines with Rational slope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume the 3-D torus is obtained by rotating a circle of radius $b$ along a line at a distance $a > b$ from its center.

With a suitable choice of origin and coordinate axis, we can parametrize the 3-D torus as

$$[-\pi,\pi] \times [-\pi,\pi] \ni (\theta,\phi)
\quad\mapsto\quad ((a+b\cos\theta)\cos\phi, (a+b\cos\theta)\sin\phi, b\sin\theta) \in \mathbb{R}^3$$
In this parametrization, the metric is given by

$$b^2 d\theta^2 + (a+b\cos\theta)^2d\phi^2$$
It is clear the lines for fixed $\theta$ and $\phi$ are orthogonal to each.
For the rhumb line to make a constant angle $\alpha \ne 0$ with the meridian circles (i.e the lines for fixed $\phi$), one can read off from above metric following condition for the rhumb line.
$$\frac{b d\theta}{(a + b\cos\phi) d\phi} = \cot\alpha\tag{*1}$$

When one walks along a rhumb line and complete one cycle in the $\theta$ direction. The change in $\phi$ will be equal to

$$\Delta\phi_{1\text{cycle}} = \tan\alpha\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{b d\theta}{a + b\cos\theta}
= 2\pi\left(\frac{b \tan\alpha}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\right)
$$

If $\displaystyle\;\frac{b\tan\alpha}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}} = \frac{m}{n}\;$ is rational, then after one walks along a rhumb line and complete $n$ cycle in the $\theta$ direction, the total change in $\phi$ will be $2\pi m$ and the rhumb line meet itself.

In short, the other rhumb lines are given by those angles $\alpha$ where
$\displaystyle\;\frac{b\tan\alpha}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\;$ is rational.

If you want the actual equations for the rhumb lines, you can treat the condition $(*1)$ as an ODE and integrate it with change of variable $x = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$. The resulting curve is not only $C^1$ but smooth (when $a > b > 0$). Furthermore, when $\displaystyle\;\frac{b\tan\alpha}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}\;$ is rational, the curve is periodic and smooth.

The actual computation is pretty simple and I'll leave that as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure the "longitude" of each point on the torus so that
for each $2\pi$ increase in longitude you return to the same meridian circle.

You can measure the "latitude" of each point on the torus so each
$2\pi$ increase in latitude along a meridian circle returns you to the same point,
and so that the points at a fixed latitude form a circle in a plane
perpendicular to the axis of rotation.

At any point along a rhumb line, you can compute the rate of change of
longitude per unit of change of latitude.
This quantity is a function of the latitude.
Now integrate the change in longitude over one full cycle of latitude
(such as from $-\pi$ to $\pi$).

If the change in longitude for a $2\pi$ change in latitude is a
rational multiple of $2\pi$, after a finite number of $2\pi$-long cycles
of latitude you will return to the same longitude.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to add that when I mean a periodic curve, I mean a periodic differentiable curve. I will update the question to add this requirement. Because I'm afraid that with your answer we get periodic continuous curves, but those won't be necessarily differentiable.

Comment: I think achille hui gave basically the same answer, but in much more specific detail. It's unclear to me where you think the curves would fail to be differentiable in either answer. Both "latitude" and "longitude" ($\theta$ and $\phi$ in achille's answer) are strictly increasing or decreasing functions of distance traveled along the path; it's just that points whose coordinates are equivalent modulo $2\pi$ are the same point, so eventually you may repeat the points you have already visited.

Comment: Indeed I got it David.